# How do I allow people in the same socket.io room to access the same redux store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I need multiple users to be able to access the same Redux store if they are in the same socket.io room.

I've tried several tutorials.

https://github.com/Shubanshii/mad-hatter-server/tree/master/client

I add a player to an array in the reducer in Game.jsx

```
    Game.jsx
...
this.props.dispatch(addPlayer(userInfo));
...

/reducers/index.js
...
switch (action.type) {
...
    case actions.ADD_PLAYER:
      handleAddPlayer();

      break;

...

function handleAddPlayer() {
    let player = {
      index: 0,
      userInfo: action.userInfo,
      stackSize: 100,
      inHand: true,
      playerTurn: true,
      playerIndex: 0,
      smallBlind: true,
      bigBlind: false,
      contributedTowardsToPlay: 0,
      hasChecked: false
    };
    modifiedState.playerInfo.push(player);
  }
```

I expect to be able to login in one tab, then switch to an incognito window, log in as a different user, then join the same room, and have the redux store show both players in both tabs.

Comment: Does one user logged in currently "show up" in the tab?

Comment: Yes.  I log in as one user, then open up an incognito window and log in as another.  I then set up a socket room and join it.  Then I have the other user join the same room.  Both users show up in the array respective to their own tab.  So the array length is one in each tab.  There is a notification that the user has joined that gets console logged in the other tab.